# Visiting islands around Cuba

Tags: airports, amsterdam, islands, caribbean, hav

I planned to travel to Cuba and Dominican Republic, but I've suddenly realized that the flights between Havana and Punta Cana are 6-8 hours and it is not that cheap...

Is there any other international airport easy to reach from Havana or Santiago? (I need to  return to Amsterdam).

Comment: Could you please indicate what you're after in a place to visit?  There are dozens of countries around Cuba, let alone islands.  Do you have a price range? Do you want to go diving? How long do you have?  The question as it stands is rather broad covering a large geographic region, and arguably does not currently meet the [FAQ]...

Comment: @Mark Mayo ok, I've edited the question

Comment: Toronto is an international airport and only 3.5 hours from Havana, with flights from $450. Though the beaches aren't as warm as the Dominican.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Cubana de Aviación](http://cubana.cu/home/?lang=en) to go from Havana (Cuba) to Santo Domingo (Dominican Republic), then take a land transport to Punta Cana.

Additionally, you could also visit Jamaica. [Starting from December 25 2011, Air Jamaica will resume flights to Santiago de Cuba](http://www.plenglish.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=452843&Itemid=1).